# How to generate the attached Matrix output in Powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKbAE.jpg)

Hi All,

I need the output as shown in the attached pic. Both rows and columns belong to the same field.

For example in the attached pic, a transaction is satisfying scenarios TM03(rows) and TM01(columns) 23 times. There are no transactions that satisfy TM02(rows) and TM01(columns) i.e. count is 0. The field that has to be added to rows and columns is Scenario_ID and the counts should be represented by the no.of transactions satisying different combinations of scenario id's.

How do i achieve the visualization presnt in the attached pic through powerbi?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't included any of your data structure, nor any of your existing attempts. Please [edit] your question so that it may be answered.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, if the dataset is designed in a way given in the [Link](https://blog.pragmaticworks.com/power-bi-custom-visuals-sankey). Sankey chart also helps you visualize the data movement from one category to another more than the matrix visual that you have provided in the image.

Thanks.